# Python: resolve problems with my Class

Tags: python, class, optimization, coding-style

I have the following class

```
def get_percentile(obs,*args):
    lstper = []
    for arg in args:
        lstper.append(np.percentile(obs,arg))
    return lstper

get_percentile([1,2,3,4,5],25,50,75)
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

class Metric(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.max = max(args)
        self.median =np.median(args)
        self.min = min(args)
        self.percentile = get_percentile(args)
```

I cannot understand correct set of `self.percentile = get_percentile(args)` in order to get various percentiles

Comment: What do you want to get, what do you currently get? This question is massively unclear.

Comment: And what is `obs` supposed to be then? You don't pass it in.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by correct set, but one thing I notice in your code is that get_percentile takes a first argument called obs that you are not passing.

Comment: No, he is passing obs, the values that all the metrics are calculated over, but not args, the desired percentiles.

Comment: It depends. How do you want to initialize `Metric`?

Comment: In your call to `get_percentile`, you are only passing a single argument (the optional `*args` aren't give) so the `for arg in args` loop never executes.

Comment: @Junuxx it's true. all metrics are calculated without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one way to solve this would be to use named keyword arguments instead of `*args`:

```
def get_percentile(obs,*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        args = [25,50,75] # default to quartiles
    lstper = []
    for arg in args:
        lstper.append(np.percentile(obs,arg))
    return lstper

class Metric(object):
    def __init__(self, values=[], percentiles=[]):
        self.max = max(values)
        self.median =np.median(values)
        self.min = min(values)
        self.percentile = get_percentile(values, percentiles)
```

In action:

```
>>> m = Metric(range(30,300,13), [20,40,60,80])
>>> m.max
290
>>> m.percentile
[[82.0, 134.0, 186.0, 238.0]]
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep using `args`, you could give the values and the percentiles in lists (or tuples, dicts, sets, ...). This is necessary, otherwise it is impossible to tell where one ends and the other begins:

```
class Metric(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not len(args) == 2:
            raise ValueError("Usage: Metric([values],[percentiles])")
        values, percentiles = args
        self.max = max(values)
        self.median =np.median(values)
        self.min = min(values)
        self.percentile = get_percentile(values, percentiles)
```

Usage same as above.

Comment: Thanks @Junuxx but i wish to find a solution where i can use def __init__(self,*args)

Comment: @Gianni: See edit. It can be done, but it's a bit clumsy. Unless you use some way to separate the two sets of numbers in your *args, it will be impossible to tell what are the values and what are the percentiles.